# Find the number of positive integer pairs $(x,y)$ such that $\frac 1x + \frac 1y=\frac{1}{2007}$ such that $x<y$

Tags: permutations, combinations

$$2007(x+y) =xy$$
$$\implies (x-2007)(y-2007)=2007^2$$

Now the values so $x$ and $y$ should depend on the factors of $2007^2$, which is something I am not very sure about

How should I proceed?

Comment: $$
\begin{array}{rr}
x & y\\
\hline
 2008 & 4030056 \\
 2010 & 1344690 \\
 2016 & 449568 \\
 2034 & 151194 \\
 2088 & 51736 \\
 2230 & 20070 \\
 2676 & 8028 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: You can't go from $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = 2007$ to $2007(x+y) = xy$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes. Fixed it now

Comment: Since both factors are integers, you can set them equal to the factor pairs of $2007^{2}$ and be sure you haven't missed any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I assume this is a middle/high school contest problem from the year 2007.  If so, then every student going into the contest should have memorized the prime factorization of 2007 (as long as their sponsor knew this unsaid rule).

That said, if you know some basic divisibility rules, you can simplify this on the spot.  For instance, the sum of the digits of 2007 is 9, so 2007 is divisible by 9.  Doing so:
$$\frac{2007}{9} = 223$$
which no longer has a digit sum divisible by 3.  We can check primes up through $\lfloor \sqrt{223}\rfloor = 14$ for the remaining divisibility to prove to ourselves that $223$ is a prime."

Therefore, we find $2007 = 3^2 \cdot 223$ is the prime factorization, $2007^2 = 3^4 \cdot 223^2$ is its prime factorization.  Therefore $2007^2$ has $(4+1)(2+1) = 15$ positive integral divisors.

One divisor is $2007$, resulting in $2007^2 = 2007 \cdot 2007$ which in turn would result in $x=y$ so we toss that, leaving us with $14$.

By symmetry, half of these will result in $x < y$ and half will result in $y<x$, so the answer is $\frac{14}{2} = 7$.

Comment: How did you get $(4+1)(2+1)$?

Comment: @Aditya Every positive integer divisor of $3^4\cdot 223^2$ has the form $3^a\cdot 223^b$ for non-negative integers $0 \leq a \leq 4$ and $0 \leq b \leq 2$ (this is why we care about the prime factorization here).  Therefore there are $4+1$ choices for $a$ and $2+1$ choices for $b$, and since these can be chosen independently of one another, the number of choices for the divisor is the product $(4+1)(2+1)$

Comment: More generally, divisor-counting function is given in terms of the prime factorization by $$\sigma_0\left(\prod_{k=1}^n p_k^{a_k}\right) = \prod_{k=1}^n(a_k+1)$$